# Divisibility in the partition function

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

There are several formulas for the calculation of the partition function $p(n)$ of an integer $n$. The last has been found by Ken Ono in 2011. My question is: using these formulas is it possible to calculate for how many $n$ the ratio $R=\frac{p(n+2)}{p(n)}$ is an integer number? For example, the $p(6)=11$ and $p(8)=22$, so in this case, $R=2$. Is this the only case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the trivial case $p(3)/p(1)=3$, Besides the case you mention there is also $p(9)/p(7)=2.$ There cannot be more, *provided* one can show that $p(n+2)/p(n)$ is weakly monotone decreasing, as it seems to be numerically; at $n=8$ this ratio is already below $2$ at $n=8$ where it is $21/11.$ I don't know offhand how to show the weak monotonicity.

ADDED: Actually all one needs to show is that $p(n+2)/p(n)<2$ for $n \ge 8$, in order to exclude the possibility of more solutions to $p(n+2)/p(n)$ being an integer, since it can clearly not be $1$.

Comment: Since the growth of $p(n)$ is less than exponential, it is surely true that there are only finitely many solutions, and if there aren't any more up to, say, 100, then it is morally certain that what we have is all there is. I wonder, though, whether there isn't some simple way to prove the ratio is less than 2 for $n\ge8$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I like that phrase "morally certain" (+1 on comment). I'd also like a reference to any estimate showing subexponential growth.

Comment: $p(n)$ grows more-or-less as $e^{b\sqrt n}$ for some constant $b$ that I can never remember, by work of Hardy and Ramanujan. I'm sure this information is readily available, in a more precise rendition, from Wikipedia or any other online essay on partitions.